# Using jQuery to perform actions in sequence

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, sequencing, waitforimages

I am using the [fullscreenr](http://nanotux.com/blog/fullscreen/) jQuery plugin on my page. First, I hide the image, then I run fullscreenr on it using the waitforimage plugin, and then finally I use fadeIn to display it:

```
<img id="bgimg" style="display: none;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/backgrounds/<?php echo $imageData['location']; ?>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $bg = $('#bgimg');
    $bg.hide();
    var FullscreenrOptions = {  width: <?php echo $imageData['width']; ?>, height: <?php echo $imageData['height']; ?>, bgID: '#bgimg' };
    $bg.waitForImages(jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions));
    $bg.fadeIn(2500);
</script>
```

My problem is that somehow, something isn't working quite right. This works fine on my dev box, but when I try to load the page on the web, the fadeIn starts before the image is fully loaded.

I tried adding a callback to the fullscreenr function, but it had the same results. What can I do to ensure that it works properly? I also tried using $bg.load() to load fullscreenr and again, no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the `load()` code you used. It seems the best solution, so I'm unsure why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have nested function calls like `function2(function1(whatever))` the inner function will be executed first and then the outer function. So in your case the fullscreenr() call will be applied BEFORE waitForImages ... and that would explain the behavior.

On second glimpse I guess that this is what you wanted to do

```
$bg.waitForImages(function() {jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions)});
```

Comment: So I was waitForImage the return value of the fullscreenr function instead of passing a function to be called once the image was loaded? Would it be the same if I used the load() function?

Comment: *"I was passing"... I'll try this when I get hom

Comment: Did you try my suggested code? It should return the anonymous function as a callback to waitForImages instead of immediately calling fullscreenr

Comment: OK, so I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work, but then I changed it to load() instead of waitForImages and it does work.

What is the difference between passing function(){blah()} and just blah() ? How does JS/jQuery know that one is a reference to a function, and one is a function call?

Comment: If you have `var whatever = function() {anotherFunction();}` you pass a function (a.k.a. a function reference) to the variable. As soon as you call this function, `anotherFunction()` will be executed. The () parentheses trigger the immediate execution of a function. So `var whatever = anotherFunction()` will immediately execute the function and assign the result (i.e. the return value) to the variable whatever.